# Go to current cursor position when invoking command-line edit mode

Tags: bash, command-line-window

If I press `v` while using either the `vi-mode` zsh plugin or `set -o vi` in bash, it opens the line I'm working on in a full vim session.  However, this puts my cursor at the beginning at the beginning of the line.  Is it possible to keep my cursor where I invoked the `v` command?  I would like this for doing quick text manipulation that isn't possible with the basic command-line mode.

I'm referring specifically to the `vi-mode` zsh implementation, but a bash solution would be welcome too.

Comment: this should work already, if EDITOR=vim

Comment: For bash you could set `VISUAL` to a script that first determines the column and then starts vim with `vim "+call cursor(1, $column)" "$@"`. So Vim is not the problem, the problem is how to determine the cursor position. This is a question that might be better ask in a community with bash experts.

Comment: @Mass I don't think so

Comment: look at the file `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Zle/edit-command-line`, it should contain the comment `Open the editor, placing the cursor at the right place if we know how.` and code to do so.  If you don't have that, possibly your zsh is older.